# Do all variables in a class have to be created in the initialization

Tags: python, class

I am learning classes and I have an exercise to create a class that does some string function. One should get a string and the other should print the string but I was wondering if you really need to create the variable under `def __init__:` This is what the answer is supposed to look like:

```
class InputOutString(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = ""

    def getString(self):
        self.s = raw_input()

    def printString(self):
        print self.s.upper()
```

I was thinking that it would be a lot more convenient to just create the variable when you get the raw input.

Comment: why don't you just forget `getString()` and put the input during initialization?

Comment: looks like Python as written by a Java developer. No you don't have to initialize them but it is good practice.

Comment: You might also want to use `def __repr__(self)` instead of `def printString(self)`.
`def __repr__(self)` will set the behavior of your variable when you'll use the print function on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Must all Python instance variables be declared in def __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274179/must-all-python-instance-variables-be-declared-in-def-init)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must all Python instance variables be declared in def \_\_init\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274179/must-all-python-instance-variables-be-declared-in-def-init)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinda.

Python does not force you to do it, but it can sometimes lead to problems if you don't.

For example - If, in your example, you do not initalise `s` in `__init__` then `printString` would raise an exception if you hadn't called `getString` yet. However if you did initialise it (as you have in your example) then it would print an empty string instead - which in many cases would be desirable.

Initalising all variables in `__init__` gives you a guarantee of sorts that they will all exist when they are required. That is why it is good practice.

Another reason you should do it, is it makes python's life easier [when determining the amount of memory required to store your class](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/#split-table-dictionaries). Python will detect the attributes being set in `__init__` and allocate size accordingly. If you then change this (by saving new attributes on the class it didn't expect) then you could end up with your class taking up double the memory overhead for each instance. (Thanks @ShadowRanger for pointing this out)

Comment: It's also useful for reducing memory usage when many instance of the object are created. Failing to initialize all instance attributes in `__init__` can break the [key sharing `dict` optimization from PEP 412](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/#split-table-dictionaries); by doing so, you'd roughly double the memory overhead per instance by requiring each instance to store their own copy of the attribute names and hashes, not just the values.

Comment: Today I learned. I'll add that to the answer. It's always good to learn from a fellow Shadow :P